# Filter a SharePoint list view with JSON?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, json-formatting, person-or-group

I would like to be able to filter the list view by group column.

I know this is possible through [SharePoint designer 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53997/filter-by-group), but I would like to do it through JSON formatting, is this possible?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint JSON formatting can only customize how fields and views in SharePoint lists and libraries are displayed.

Unfortunately, you cannot check group membership or group permissions using JSON formatting.

**Documentation**: [SharePoint column-formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

---

**Similar threads**:

1. [Show hide columns based on the logged in user using JSON formaating](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303095/show-hide-columns-based-on-the-logged-in-user-using-json-formaating/303096#303096)
2. [JSON how to check @me belong to particular SharePoint group](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299456/json-how-to-check-me-belong-to-particular-sharepoint-group/299458#299458)